# M2 Can't add new Checkout Step

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, knockoutjs, component

I'm following the Magento dev docs [Add a new checkout step](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html) how to guide.  But I get the following error in my browser console once I go to the checkout...

```
GET http://example.test/checkout/Holy_CheckoutTuts/js/view/my-step-view.js net::ERR_ABORTED    require.js:1895 

[ERROR] Failed to load the "Holy_CheckoutTuts/js/view/my-step-view.js" component.    console-output-handler.js:34
```

I've declared the component in my modules `checkout_index_index.xml`...

```
app/code/Holy/CheckoutTuts/
├── etc
│   └── module.xml
├── composer.json
├── registration.php
└── view
    └── frontend
        ├── layout
        │   └── checkout_index_index.xml
        └── web
            ├── js
            │   └── view
            │       └── my-step-view.js
            └── template
                └── mystep.html
```

-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <!--<item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">-->
                                            <!--<item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>-->
                                            <!--<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>-->
                                            <!--<item name="children" xsi:type="array">-->
                                                <!--<item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">-->
                                                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Holy_CheckoutTuts/js/view/my-step-view.js</item>&ndash;&gt;-->
                                                    <!--<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>-->
                                                    <!--<item name="children" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
                                                <!--</item>-->
                                            <!--</item>-->
                                        <!--</item>-->
                                        <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Holy_CheckoutTuts/js/view/my-step-view.js</item>
                                            <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                            <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                            <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  I had left the `.js` extension when I declared the js file to use for my component.

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Holy_CheckoutTuts/js/view/my-step-view.js</item>
```

I should of used...

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Holy_CheckoutTuts/js/view/my-step-view</item>
```